# Appstore icon glossy effect?

Tags: ios, xcode

I know that in order to disable any gloss effect on my icon, on the device and on the Appstore (512x512), I have to set in my `Info.plist` file:

```
Icon already includes glossary effect: YES
```

But I have read here, that there is something called : `UIPrerenderedIcon` that i couldn't find.

Is the first boolean in the plist file which I mentioned above good enough or do I need both?

Comment: Did you get your question answered? If so, choose an answer below that solved your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIPrerenderedIcon` and `Icon already includes glossary effect` are one and the same. The `Icon already includes glossary effect` is the readable representation of `UIPrerenderedIcon` by the Plist editor included in XCode.

To know for sure, `right click on you plist file` > `Open As` > `Source Code` and you'll see the names of all the values set. Amongst them you'll find `UIPrerenderedIcon`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `YES` on `UIPrerenderedIcon` should disable the gloss effect on your icon.